# Direct2d CreateSharedBitmap crashes

Tags: directx-11, direct2d, dxgi

I'm trying to create a shared bitmap to share a D3D11Texture2d with Direct2d rendering. After creating the texture and render target I attempt to make a shared bitmap, however the call crashes with a memory access error within d2d1!GetParentTexture. My code as follows:

```
UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL reqFeatureLevels[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
};

CComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
    NULL,                      // specify null to use the default adapter
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    0,
    creationFlags,              // optionally set debug and Direct2D compatibility flags
    reqFeatureLevels,              // list of feature levels this app can support
    ARRAYSIZE(reqFeatureLevels),   // number of possible feature levels
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &device,                    // returns the Direct3D device created
    NULL,                       // returns feature level of device created
    &context                    // returns the device immediate context
);
if (FAILED(hr)) return -1;
CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> renderTexture;
CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, 100, 100, 1, 1, D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET);
textureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;
hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &renderTexture);
if (FAILED(hr)) return -1;

CComPtr<IDXGISurface> dxgiSurf;
hr = renderTexture.QueryInterface<IDXGISurface>(&dxgiSurf);
OnHResult(hr, "QueryInterface<IDXGISurface>", return false);
DXGI_SURFACE_DESC desc;
dxgiSurf->GetDesc(&desc);
CComPtr<ID2D1Factory> factory;
hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, __uuidof(ID2D1Factory), NULL, (void**)&factory);
if (FAILED(hr)) return -1;

CComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget> renderTarget;
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT, D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE));
hr = factory->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(dxgiSurf, &props, &renderTarget);
if (FAILED(hr)) return -1;

CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> sharedBitmap;
D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES bitmapProperties = D2D1::BitmapProperties(D2D1::PixelFormat(desc.Format, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE));
hr = renderTarget->CreateSharedBitmap(IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgiSurf), &bitmapProperties, &sharedBitmap);
if (FAILED(hr)) return -1;
```

Any ideas why this fails?

Answer (score 0):

You pass `IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgiSurf),` as first two parameters of `CreateSharedBitmap`. This macro expands into
`IID_IDXGISurface, reinterpret_cast< void * * >(&dxgiSurf)`
while the second parameter should be reinterpret_cast< void * >(p_dxgi_surface)` so an extra pointer dereference happens and program crashes.